# Odoo Server Error: ValueError: Invalid Field 'Validator_user_ids' in leaf

Tags: python, odoo

we are using Odoo 8.0 on Windows2012 Server platform, once windows server restarted our Odoo stat giving the following Odoo Server Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\http.py", line 574, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\http.py", line 310, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\http.py", line 307, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\http.py", line 803, in **call**
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 878, in load_needaction
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\http.py", line 908, in proxy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\api.py", line 250, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_menu.py", line 345, in get_needaction_data
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\api.py", line 250, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_needaction.py", line 64, in _needaction_count
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\api.py", line 250, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\models.py", line 1645, in search
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\api.py", line 250, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\models.py", line 4672, in _search
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\api.py", line 250, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\models.py", line 4483, in _where_calc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\osv\expression.py", line 657, in **init**
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20151102\server.\openerp\osv\expression.py", line 823, in parse
ValueError: Invalid field 'validator_user_ids' in leaf "

I will appreciate any guidance to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One of your domain is not properly written (the field may not exist, not a field that you can perform a query on, etc.). Of course we can't know which one because we do not have access to your code. It happened after the server restart because python files are re-processed when you do so. So it is a domain that is in a python file.